# Problem when trying to delete row from DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, datarow

I've got a DataTable floating in a session variable, that is tied to a GridView.

I've programmed a Delete button into the GridView, which calls a method to delete that row as follows

```
private void DeleteRecordByID(int ID)
{
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["tempPermissions"];
    DataRow rowDelete = dt.Rows[ID];
    dt.Rows.Remove(rowDelete);
}
```

I've got two test records sitting in my DataTable that get loaded from a database.

My issue is that when I click delete on a record, I get the following error

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: There is no row at position 22.
```

Even though there is a record in the DataTable that has ID of 22..

Anybody know why this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The indexer is expecting the *index* of the row, not the *ID*.

Your rows may be

```
1
15
29
31
```

But the indexes are merely 0 through 3.

There are several methods of finding a row within a DataTable, ranging from built-in methods on DataTable to using LINQ. A DataTable-centered method is to define a primary key column on the table, such as

```
DataColumn idColumn = dt.Columns["ID"];
dt.PrimaryKey = new[] { idColumn };
```

This allows you to use the `DataTable.Rows.Find(object key)` method to retrieve your row.

```
DataRow row = dt.Rows.Find(22);
```

If no row exists with the given key, the result will be `null`. As such, validate against null before doing any operations with the output.

Comment: Ok that makes sense.. Is there a way to retrieve the index of a row?

Answer (score 0):

Note that you may also need to do a GridView.DataBind() after the delete.